# Не получается сделать кнопку удаления в laravel с помощью Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

Все привет. У меня возникла проблема при удаление. Я делаю проект на laravel. Использую datatables для таблицы и ajax. В вообщем, когда я нажимаю на кнопку 'Delete' у меня выходит следующая ошибка.

DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/company/4 404 (Not Found)

Не понимаю в чем проблема.Помогите пожалуйста.
Вот мой код:

```
//company.blade.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel 8 Datatable Example</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h3><strong>Laravel 8 Datatable Example</strong></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered data-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    th width="50">No</th>
                        <th>Компания</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Адрес</th>
                        <th>Логотип</th>
                        <th width="100px">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
    });
 });
 $(function () {
    var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ route('company.index') }}",
        columns: [
            {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
            {data: 'company', name: 'company'},
            {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
            {data: 'addres', name: 'addres'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
        ]
    });
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.deleteBook', function () {

var book_id = $(this).data("id");
confirm("Are You sure want to delete !");

$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: "{{ route('company.destroy') }}"+'/'+book_id,
    success: function (data) {
        table.draw();
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('Error:', data);
    }
});
});

</script>
</html>

//контроллер
 public function destroy($id)
    {
        Company::find($id)->delete();

        return response()->json(['success'=>'Company deleted successfully.']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам сказано, что страница с таким адресом url {{ route('company.destroy') }}"+'/'+book_id не найдена. Необходимо добавить этот маршрут.

Comment: Я добавил маршрут в роутах, но теперь выдает ошибку Missing required parameter for [Route: company.destroy] [URI: company/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]. (View: C:\Users\pavel1988\Desktop\open_server_5_3_7_basic_full\OpenServer\domains\company\resources\views\company.blade.php)

Comment: Route::delete('/company/{id}', [CompanyController::class, 'destroy'])->name('company.destroy');

Comment: Параметр в маршрут передаётся вот так `route('company.destroy',['id'=>$book_id])` Посмотрите подробнеее документацию по маршрутам.

Comment: Liudmila Savateeva, Ваш ответ мне очень помог.Я сделал следующим образом:  
Route::delete('/company/{id}/destroy', [CompanyController::class, 'destroy'])->name('company.destroy');    в blade я сделал так:$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: "{{ (url('/company')) }}"+'/'+book_id+'/destroy',